# PeakVirtualMemorySize64, PeakWorkingSet64 and PeakPagedMemorySize64 for a process have different value if we executed several time?

Tags: .net, windows, performance, memory, internals

I run a code multiple time and i measure in the end of it the PeakPagedMemorySize64 , PeakWorkingSet64 and PeakVirtualMemorySize64 using the Process class .

But in each time i get different value for the same code

```
PeakPagedMemorySize64 112758784 PeakVirtualMemorySize64 332701696   PeakWorkingSet64 143835136
PeakPagedMemorySize64 113696768 PeakVirtualMemorySize64 332636160   PeakWorkingSet64 144642048
PeakPagedMemorySize64 113528832 PeakVirtualMemorySize64 332701696   PeakWorkingSet64 144547840
```

why I have this different values instead of getting the same value each time? And how can I optimize it to minimize this variation?

Comment: Always go through the documentation first:- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html

Comment: @Ankit  I'm not talking about Heap Program but the total of memory used means working set and virtual memory

Comment: @ankit is it more clear now after editing the question ?

Answer (score 1):

"Working set" is the amount of virtual memory which fits into physical RAM. The amount of physical RAM available depends on other programs as well, so this value changes over time. If the "working set" value changes due to other programs, so will the peak value.

In fact, you should be happy if this value is high: this means that all your data is in RAM and RAM is fast. If this value is low, some data has been swapped to disk and disk is very slow.

The question is: why do you want to measure this value? If you're looking for a memory leak, measure private bytes instead.

Since you have tagged this [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), the amount of private bytes heavily depends on the implementation of the .NET garbage collector. It may request more or less memory depending on garbage collections which ran or did not run previously and how much physical RAM was available at the time .NET requested additional memory the last time.

To see those internals, I recommend using [windbg](/questions/tagged/windbg) and [sos](/questions/tagged/sos). You can then see the amount of free memory of the .NET garbage collector.

Comment: "Working set" is the amount of virtual memory which fits into physical RAM, but it's for the current process how much phyisical memory he is using ?

Comment: the same variation is also for private bytes , i'm not trying to find a leak but just trying to know how much memory the code or process cosumme, but if this value is different each time, means it's not accurate

Comment: evenif their is no garbage collection, i get variations.

Comment: How did you check that there are no garbage collections?

Comment: display  GC.CollectionCount(0), GC.CollectionCount(1), GC.CollectionCount(2)

Comment: .NET may allocate more memory if there was more free memory available the last time memory needed to be allocated.

Comment: Ah really can i get the sources to find this info about .net allocation ?

Comment: Ok, now I see what you want... I think I read about it in http://www.amazon.de/dp/0321578899/ Unfortunately I'm on vacation in the moment and I don't have that book with me. Perhaps I could write an example program demonstrating it by setting breakpoints in `VirtualAlloc`

Comment: What is your system specs? 64 bit OS, <=12 GB RAM, 8 cores?

Comment: Yes, that's it i have the book and i can't find the part which it say "NET may allocate more memory if there was more free memory available"

Comment: i need just to understand why we have the interval if it's the same program for a working set and virtual memory, The paged is okey so we will have less page file if we have lot of free memory space , but what about the other metrics ?

Comment: Please hold on. I finished part one, a program which consumes much physical RAM. I'm working on a .NET program allocating RAM under good and bad circumstances. Third are the debugging steps to proove what's going on. It'll take a while...